# Sugerencias de crear historicos de tablas de BD

Tags: base-de-datos

alguien podría por favor proporcionarme sugerencias para, de alguna manera guardar todos los históricos de una tabla, ejemplo un tabla x el cual sufre cambios constantemente, quiero de alguna manera guardar todos los estados que tuvo ese registro, cuando fue modificado y demás, por ejemplo estaba pensando en una tabla genérica que tenga como campos tabla, usuario, acción, fecha y un json que contenga el registro histórico de todos los campos.

Comment: Tienes varias opciones, una de ellas, es replicar la estructura de la tabla y copiar los datos en ella cada vez que se modifican, teniendo un campo ue te permita ver los cambios. Otra, que es la que yo suelo usar en el trabajo, es crear una tabla con los campos que se han de modificar y guardar ahi el históric. Pero como bien se te ha comentado antes, deberías proporcionar mas info, para ayudarte

Comment: en un sólo campo por producto puedes registrar los cambios como incremento.
Por ejemplo el incremento de precio es igual al precio inicial o supuesto más el precio adquirido.
La fecha se incrementa en el mismo campo...
Después se descompone el dato del campo con lenguaje de programación.
El lenguaje que uses tanto de programación como para la BD son independientes de la logica.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deberías proporcionar más información acerca del motor de DB que usas. Podrías tener como alternativa implementar a nivel de DB un trigger cuando se producen estos eventos del CRUD.

Los triggers se disparan según los configures antes de un evento sobre una tabla; sería lo ideal para no preocuparse de ello desde el sistema. El ideal de la tabla que almacena el histórico como una auditoría sería que fuese idéntica e incluyera un id único en ella, y ambas tablas deberían contar como mínimo con usuario_create, fecha_create y usuario_update, fecha_update para hacerle una traza al registro.

> Si estaba pensando en algo asi, pero lo que no me agrada es que por cada tabla tendría que crear una tabla idéntica de auditoría. Por eso estaba pensando en la de una tabla de auditoría genérica para todas las tablas, que tenga sus datos de auditorio, y un campo que tenga un JSON que en sí contendría todos los históricos de todas las tablas. Y bueno con el trigger todas las tablas podría hacer un insert a esa tabla genérica.

El problema con eso en DB relacionales sería lo costoso que podría resultar hacer una búsqueda, cuanto menos deberías considerar los campos [ ID, TABLE_REFERENCE, ID_REFERENCE, DATA_JSON ] aún así es costoso buscar en caso que se requiera verificar la traza reciente de un registro. Lo que te recomendaría sería validar la volumetría y variabilidad de los registros, ya que si es baja podría ser una opción a considerar.

Comment: Creo que para el caso no tiene mucha relevancia el motor, ya que la idea es que se aplique a cualquier SGBDR, y bueno en cuanto al trigger, es una opción pero creo que sería de como detectar el evento y almacenarlo, pero mas que todo la idea es como hacer el modelo de la base de datos para los historicos de una base de datos o algo asi, ejemplo una tabla identica a otra que guarde los historicos, un generica que guarde todo en json, etc.

Comment: Si estaba pensando en algo asi, pero lo que no me agrada es que por cada tabla tendría que crear una tabla identica de auditoria. Por eso estaba pensando en la de una tabla de auditoria generica para todas las tablas, que tenga sus datos de auditorio, y un campo que tenga un joson que en si contendria todos los hiastoricos  de todas las tablas. Y bueno con el triger todas las tablas podría hace un insert a esa tabla genercia.